# How to correctly configure Imagine in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I had a requirement in laravel, where i needed to some server side cropping using the the laravel package **[Imagine](https://github.com/orchestral/imagine#installation)**, now i followed the installation instruction for this package for my application, I.E. :

I added the below line in my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "orchestra/imagine": "~3.0"
    }
}
```

My `composer.json` file looks like below now:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master",
        "orchestra/imagine": "~3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Now when i run `composer update` from the terminal , i get the following messages:

[image: Message]

and i have now followed **[THESE INSTRUCTIONS](https://github.com/orchestral/imagine#configuration)** too, of adding the alias etc to the `config/app.php`,

Now when i try to load my admin panel , i get the following error:

```
Class 'Orchestra\Imagine\ImagineServiceProvider' not found
```

Why am i getting this error , can somebody explain ?

Comment: Did you use `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @aldrin27 for what do i need to run that command ?

Comment: What happened? Any error?

Comment: @aldrin27 what u see in my question is what i get !

Answer (score 2):

You are using laravel 4.2.* and  imagine "~3.0" with it.   imagine "~3.0" is for laravel 5.1. So try using correct version. Version compatibility image below

[image]